# How to sort QMap<QString, myStruct>?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qsort, qmap

I have a `QMap<QString, myStruct>` with

```
myStruct {
    QString firstname;
    QString lastname;
    QString status;
}
```

How can I sort this `QMap` according to priority order: `status` then `firstname` then `lastname`?

Comment: Perhaps you should use another container, since [`QMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html) is always sorted *on the key!*

Comment: Actually this QMap is fixed and I can not changed any more :(. So I am thinking about another solution: because the key in my case is unique, So I would take out all the values as `QList<QStringList>` and then sort this `QList`, after that put the sorted list into QMap again. How do you think about that solution?

Comment: That won't help. When you insert back into the map, it will be "resorted" according to the key again. Depending on your use-case you might want to use two containers. First the map, which is sorted by the key. Then a vector (or similar) with reference-wrappers to the structure in the map. You can sort the vector any way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you'd like to retrieve the values of the map sorted in the mentioned way, but still have access to the key. Right?

Quickly speaking, a map is a collection of `<key, value>` pairs automatically sorted by *key*, then you may try a list of `<value, key>` pairs manually sorted by *value* instead. Something like `QList<QPair<myStruct, QString>>`, while overriding the `operator<` for `myStruct`.

```
struct myStruct {
    QString firstname;
    QString lastname;
    QString status;

    bool operator<(const myStruct& o) const {
      return std::tie(status, firstname, lastname) <
             std::tie(o.status, o.firstname, o.lastname);
    }
};

QMap<QString, myStatus> map; // your original map
QList<QPair<myStatus, QString>> inv;

// Populate the inverted list
for (auto k : map.keys()) {
  inv.append(QPair<myStatus, QString>(map[k], k));
}

std::sort(std::begin(inv), std::end(inv));

for (auto p : inv) {
  qDebug() << p.first.status << p.first.firstname << p.first.lastname << p.second;
}
```

Of course, it is a one-time use structure that doesn't keep updated with your original map, but you mentioned that the map is *fixed* (constant?) so it may not be a problem then.

BTW, a `QMap` can be used for the inverse look-up but only in the case the values of the `myStruct` part are also unique (so they can be used also as a key), otherwise you may overwrite values when constructing the inverse map.

*Note:* The `std::tie` is used just to simplify the sorting condition for tuples (so you'd need to include `<tuple>`).

**UPDATE**

Answering one of your comments: Yes, you can also specify your own comparison predicate and then avoid overriding the `operator<`, but I think it is harder to read and less re-usable:

```
std::sort(std::begin(inv), std::end(inv),
  [](const QPair<myStatus, QString>& lhs, const QPair<myStatus, QString>& rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.first.status, lhs.first.firstname, lhs.first.lastname) <
           std::tie(rhs.first.status, rhs.first.firstname, rhs.first.lastname);
});
```

Of course, you can implement that comparison lambda as you want, I've used the `std::tie` again to simplify the logic in the post. The downside is that if you need to generate the inverse map in several places you'd have to repeat the lambda expression everywhere (or create a function to create the inverse map of course).

As a side note and in case you are curious, `lhs` and `rhs` refers to *left-hand side* and *right-hand side* respectively, in this case they are used as `lhs < rhs` by the sorting algorithm for comparing the elements.

Finally, if you'd want to avoid the `std::tie` you'd have to make the comparisons manually (code below modifies the `operator<` of the first version):

```
bool operator<(const myStruct& o) const {
  if (status < o.status) return true;
  if (status > o.status) return false;
  // status == o.status, move to next attribute

  if (firstname < o.firstname) return true;
  if (firstname > o.firstname) return false;
  // firstname== o.firstname, move to next attribute

  if (lastname < o.lastname) return true;
  if (lastname > o.lastname) return false;

  return false; // are equal
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @cbuchart. Your solution is really brilliant. But there is one thing i dont understand. You overwrite `operator<`, but I dont see where it is used. Could you explain a little bit clearer?

Comment: Besides, do we have another algorithm except for `std::tie` to sort elements, so that we dont have to overwrite anything?

Comment: @gnase the `operator<` is used by the [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to, well, sort the list. The [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is used to simplify the code of the comparison, ow you'd need to contemplate all the cases manually.

Comment: thanks a lot @cbuchart. I understand more through your answer. I accepted it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a `QMap` manually, you'll have to use a `QList` (or `QVector`) for that and use `std::sort` on it. Use `QMap::values()` to extract the values (structs) from the map into a list, then implement a compare function/method and call it with `std::sort`. See *cbuchart*s answer for some hints how to do this.

Keeping map and list in sync when the values change is a different issue, if this is a requirement you should create a separate question, adding a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and more details on what you tried.